# How to find AVG of Count in SQL

Tags: sql, count, average

This is what I have

select avg(visit_count) from ( SELECT count(user_id) as visit_count from table )group by user_id;

But I get the below error

ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

if I add alias
then I get avg for only one user_id

What I want is the avg of visit_count for all user ids

[SEE the picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G8UQ.png)

Example 3,2.5,1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your subquery needs to have an alias.

Like this:

```
select avg(visit_count) from (
  select count(user_id) as visit_count from table
   group by user_id) a
```

Comment: Its working but the output is average for only one user_id, how can I have avg of count for all user ids??

Comment: You need to include user_id and group by it in your outer query. `select user_id, avg(visit_count) from (
  select user_id, count(user_id) as visit_count from table
   group by user_id) a
   group by user_id`

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is missing an alias.  I think this is the version you want:

```sql
SELECT AVG(visit_count)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS visit_count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY user_id
) t;
```

Note that `GROUP BY` belongs inside the subquery, as you want to find counts for all users.

Comment: Its working but the output is average for only one user_id, how can I have avg of count for all user ids??

Comment: My answer gives you the average count for all users.  Did you actually try running my code?